# SQL result returning total rows instead of specified

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I have this query

```
SELECT p.*, total, active_total
FROM proxies p
LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT proxy_id, COUNT(*) as total 
        FROM creator_log 
        GROUP BY proxy_id) p2
        ON p.proxy_id = p2.proxy_id
JOIN 
        (SELECT proxy_id, COUNT(*) as active_total 
        FROM accounts
        WHERE status = 1) p3
        ON p.proxy_id = p3.proxy_id
WHERE 
    p.proxy_status = '1'
ORDER BY 
    p2.proxy_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The value for `active_total` is returning the total number of rows inside my `accounts` table, It's supposed to find accounts that have the `proxy_id` returned from the `LEFT JOIN` result,

Any ideas why it's performing weird?

Comment: Do you have `proxy_id` in `accounts` table?

Comment: Didn't you forget to apply `GROUP BY` in your second subquery `p3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your accounts table has following entries

```
proxy_id    |  field1   
   1           some_value     
   2           some_value     
   3           some_value     
   4           some_value
```

And query

```
SELECT proxy_id, COUNT(*) as active_total 
FROM accounts
WHERE status = 1
```

result

```
proxy_id    |  active_total 
   1            4
```

So when left join, your expected result won't get. It result only the total records

Try this

```
SELECT p.*, total, active_total
FROM proxies p
LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT proxy_id, COUNT(*) as total 
        FROM creator_log 
        GROUP BY proxy_id) p2
        ON p.proxy_id = p2.proxy_id
JOIN 
        (SELECT proxy_id, COUNT(proxy_id) as active_total 
        FROM accounts
        WHERE status = 1
        GROUP BY proxy_id ) p3
        ON p.proxy_id = p3.proxy_id
WHERE 
    p.proxy_status = '1'
ORDER BY 
    p2.proxy_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```